# Generate (*.tps) from command-line tool?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, texturepacker

I'm currently writing a batch script to generate sprite sheets using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)'s Command-line Tool.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b sprites') do (
    TexturePacker --format "json" --data "sheets/%%i.json" --sheet "sheets/%%i.png" "sprites/%%i"
)
```

Quite simple so far but I was wondering if it were possible to generate a [*.tps] file from the tool as well. So that if someone wants to check the properties of the export they can do so through the TexturePackerGUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bash script I use to build all .tps files in a folder:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.tps; do TexturePacker assets/texture_packer/$i; done
```

Comment: but it wouldn't gnerate new tps file, looks like by deault TexturePacker doesnot genertae the .tps file, how to generate one from command line ?

Answer (score -1):

This batch script generate all *.tps in folder:

```
for /R %%f in (*.tps) do "c:\Program Files\CodeAndWeb\TexturePacker\bin\TexturePacker.exe" %%f
```